# Why is "appeal to nature" a fallacy?

Tags: logic, ethics, fallacies, philosophy-of-logic

Appeal to nature states that just because something is natural doesn't mean it is right (ethical). Morality is not objective but the existence of this fallacy attempts to objectively define morality by making this arbitrary exception; if a new philosophy of 'everything that is natural is good' emerged, how would it be fallacious if morality is by definition a subjective concept?

Comment: It is perhaps fallacious if used to *impose* a conclusion upon someone or within some framework that does not take the assumption or premise that natural is inherently good. In other words, it may be a fallacy if used to imply a premise not agreed upon. Consider also that *appeal to nature* as a category is not only with respect to morality. One may use it to suggest safety or better health outcome, which may be a false assumption.

Comment: Maybe Nietzsche would have found natural equivalent to "right" in his view of morality - he seems to go in that direction in some of his writings, if I understand him correctly.

Comment: Using a natural product like arsenic to murder someone is an example that a natural thing may be used for immoral purposes.

Comment: "Morality is not objective but the existence of this fallacy attempts to objectively define morality by making this arbitrary exception" No. The fallacy consists simply in assuming that naturalness says anything about morality. Without further assumptions, there is no reason to believe why "If it is natural then it is ethical" would be valid. And if there is no reason to believe that a principle would be universally valid (even though it may be true in some cases), that's what we call a fallacy.

Comment: @Lemontree By that definition of a fallacy, all philosophical beliefs about subjective concepts such as ethics are fallacies. Eg. A steals from B, C is asked why they opposed what they just saw, they respond "It's unethical", when they are pushed further, they keep repeating "It's just unethical!", ie; the core of their argument is based off of subjectivity (ethics) so it is fallacious. You could also say 'Without further assumptions, there is no reason to believe why "If it involves harm to another human being then it is unethical" is valid' because the 'reason' is just an emotional response.

Comment: Morality is not "by definition a subjective concept". One of the most significant arguments in philosophy is over whether morality is objective or not. The people who argue that morality is objective are not simply misusing the term.

Comment: Naturalistic fallacy, that natural things are also good, may be a fallacy in some cases. Insisting on it being a fallacy leads to the anti-naturalistic fallacy, that good is always unrelated to anything natural.

Comment: Those who would explicitly assert that 'everything that is natural is good' in their argument would not be committing this fallacy, so its existence does not stop them from defining anything. However, they'll face a bigger problem of defining "natural" in a way that makes their idea of "good" coherent and not unappealing to almost everybody. The fallacy is in attempting to sneak in a premise without taking the fall for it.